# What does "[&]" mean in C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading to an open source project. I am not able to understand what this snippet does ?

```cpp
EXPORT Result LoaderParse(LoaderContext *Cxt, Context **Module, const char *Path) {
    return wrap([&]() {
        return fromloa(Cxt)->parse(std::filesystem::absolute(Path));
      }, [&](auto &&Res) {
          *Mod = toAST((*Res).release());
      }, Cxt, Module);
}


template <typename T, typename U, typename... CxtT>
inline Result wrap(T &&Proc, U &&Then, CxtT *...Cxts) noexcept {
    if (isC(Cxts...)) {
        if (auto Res = Proc()) {
            Then(Res);
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me what does `[&]` do in this case?

Comment: That's a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-170) afaik.

Comment: It means to capture all accessible to this closure variables by reference

Comment: ... Which is often not a wise thing to do

Comment: `[&]()` is **the beginning** of a lambda expression.  The full lambda expression is `[&](){ ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[&]` alongside with `[=]` [denotes a `capture-default` policy for the given lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> - `&` (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by reference) and
> - `=` (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by copy).

For your particular case it means that two first closures (arguments) passed to the `wrap` function can access all variables in the given context (`Cxt`, `Module` and `Path`) by reference. There are other side effects a capture list may introduce, e.g. the lambda has deleted copy-assignment operator in C++20 and cannot be casted into a function pointer.